# How can I get the post data in a collection format in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, forms, post

I am wondering how I can get the post data in a collection format?
Say if I have a form and one textbox named firstname, normally i type

```
var fn = txtFirstName.Text;
```

to get the data from that textbox. but I am wondering when i click on submit data to post the form how i can get the collection of raw post data?

thank you.

I want to get the post data instead of get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the Request object directly. It is a collection of all the form elements. You can loop through them or access them by name as follows:

`Request["txtFirstName"]`

**EDIT:** If however, there's a querystring variable with the same name, that will be used first. In that case, `Request.Form["txtFirstName"]` should be used to instead.

Answer (score 3):

Request["txtFirstName"] will actually give you the URL argument, like:

http://www.example.com/Page.aspx?txtFirstName=value

If you want the value that is posted to the page from an input with the name `txtFirstName` you want **Request.Form["txtFirstName"]**

Comment: @JerSchneid - both Request["txtFirstName"] and Request.Form["txtFirstName"] bring back the same result provided there isn't a querystring with the same name.